# How to understand the equivalence between Andreev reflection and Cooper pair injection?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, superconductivity

It is well know that Andreev reflection dominates the subgap transport at the normal metal-superconductor interface. An incident electron can be reflected as a hole in the Nambu space, which effectively describes two electrons transmit into the superconductor and form a Cooper pair. It seems reasonable and intuitive that the two pictures are equivalent to each other at first glance. However, it is not so easy for me to understand this fact.

[image] Fig.1

In the electron-hole picture as shown in Fig.1 (PRB 25, 4515 (1982)), an electron in |+k> state is incident from the normal side. Then it will transmit into the superconductor by pulling another electron in |−k> state to form a Cooper pair. The empty state in |−k> is called a hole, and the moving direction of the hole is opposite to the incident electron, so that this phenomenon is called Andreev "reflection". Based on this picture, the incident electron and reflected hole possess nearly the same momentum of +k (note that the empty state in |−k> has a momentum of +k). Therefore, the whole Andreev process occurs with momentum conservation.

[image] Fig.2

Now let's turn to the two-electron picture by a redeﬁnition of the vacuum as shown in Fig.2 (Eur. Phys. J. B 40, 379–396 (2004)). In this picture, two electrons incident from the normal side both transmit into the superconductor, and they possess nonzero total momentum. (note that Fig.2 sketches the opposite process where two electrons are injected from the superconductor into the normal metal, however, the argument is similar.) So when they form a Cooper pair in the superconductor, their total momentum must be changed, for the Cooper pair has zero momentum.

Based on the argument above, we see that the Andreev reflection is a process with the momentum conservation, while the two-electron injection process breaks the momentum conservation. I believe that, if the two pictures are equivalent, then the momentum of the two physical processes——Andreev reflection and two-electron injection, must be equal to each other. In my opinion, using the Andreev reflection picture to study the transport problems is always right. However, the Andreev picture can not deal with all relevant problems. For example, when we are interested in the two electron entanglement, then the single particle process described by Andreev reflection is powerless. Therefore, to find good equivalence between the two pictures are highly nontrivial.

It is also strange that in the Andreev reflection process, an incident electron must pull an electron which is moving backward! It seems paradoxical that a back moving electron will enter the superconductor! I think that the problem occurs due to we can not treat the two electrons independently, so when we focus on the two-electron picture rather than the Andreev picture, we must take into account the interaction between two electrons. Is there any one know the method to deal with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: a few comments: 1) you can always confound an electron with momentum $k$ and a hole with momentum $-k$, thanks to the particle-hole symmetry. 2) There is no charge injection in a superconductor, since there is no charge there. 3) You should never talk of electrons, I guess what you call an electron is an excitation modes in the normal metal and the superconductor ; obviously these two excitations have nothing to do with each other, since the superconducting vacuum has nothing to do with the vacuum of the normal metal.

Comment: So the pictures you gave (and which are widely used indeed) are merely wrong. Both of them. But they still help understanding the basic process: the conversion of excitations between two radically different vacua. Last remark: in the second picture you give, $\mu_{s}$ and $\mu_{n}$ are not the same, so this effect is a non-equilibrium process : there is no need to conserve the momentum I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I believe the picture in Fig.1 is right. I got totally confused by your comment 2), why there is no charge there? Although in the superconductor, the elementary excitation is not bare electron, we can still talk about charge transfer, and there is no inconsistency here. The Andreev reflection process definitely results in charge injection, and I wonder why you don't think so.

Comment: About your comment 3), why we can never talk of electrons? Even the bare electron is not the eigenstate of superconductor, we can still investigate it, right? In the classic BTK paper, it was shown clearly the excitation in the normal metal and the superconductor are related to each other in the tunneling processes.

Comment: Here we care about the scale of nanometer, so we think the incident quasiparticles are in equilibrium, which can be described by Fermi distribution function. The scattering processes are coherent, so have nothing to do with the non-equilibrium effects.